# Run javascript/jquery after text change but before submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input element on a form along with a submit button.

I want to run the change event on the input element all whenever a change occurs.  The problem is if end user changes text and clicks submit button the code in the change event doesn't run.

Immediately after user clicks the submit button, the form submits (like the change is not getting time to run, the same occurs with blur or focus out).

My controls can be placed on any form, and I do not control the click event of the button.

Help please

Comment: You may want to try `onkeyup` event - catching the actual key presses.

Answer (score 1):

If you're wanting to catch whenever input in a textbox is changed try this in the document.ready

```
$("input[type='text']").change( function() { 
   $("#SubmitButton").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
   // check input ($(this).val()) for validity here 
   // after text is updated..etc, enable the button
   $("#SubmitButton").removeAttr('disabled');
});
```

Comment: Yes, i am currently doing that however the user is still able to change the text and then hit the submit button without the change event firing.  The form gets submitted before the change can run.

Comment: It is like the submit has started, and even though i can see visually the input value changing the submit has already started and hence i don't have the opportunity to update text value

Comment: You could disable the submit button until the change function has completed

Comment: Or like Aleks mentioned, you could try the onkeyup or the onkeypress event. $('input[type='text']').bind('keypress', function(e){})

Answer (score 0):

may be you want use [event.preventDefault](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on @Aleks G's comment, the best thing for you to do is trigger your change handling on more than just the `change` event.  Beyond `keyup`, I've found you also need to be careful to handle pasting with the mouse (doesn't trigger the keyup or change event):

```
yourInput.bind('change keyup paste', function() {
    // Your code
});
```